# Expected number of games of gambler's ruin

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Three gamblers each start with $a$, $b$ and $c$ chips, respectively.
In each round of the game, a gambler is selected uniformly at random
to give up one chip, and one of the remaining two gamblers is selected
uniformly at random to receive that chip. The game ends when there are
only two players remaining with chips, that is, one player goes
bankrupt. Let $X_n$, $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ be the respective number of chips
the three players have after round $n$, so $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0) = (a, b,  c)$.

Here, we have $M_n = X_nY_nZ_n + \frac{1}{3}n(a + b + c)$ being a martingale, and we can define $N := \inf\{n : X_nY_nZ_n = 0\}$ to be a stopping time of $M_n$. I want to show that the game terminates almost surely, i.e. $\mathrm{E}[N] < \infty$. I'm not sure how I can go about doing that.

In my attempt, I observe that I can (somewhat) extend this to a two-player gambler's ruin by "lengthening" the game to where the game ends when one gambler gets all the chips, and the game will still terminate almost surely. However, it's not exactly the same as two-player, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see how you came up with $M_n$. The stopping time $N$ makes sense, as it would be the time at which the game terminates, but the factor $\frac13n(a+b+c)$ is a bit mysterious.